# Multifield form misplacing values when submitting queries

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm working on a multifield form to register issues, but when submitting the data to the mysql db it misplaces the checkmark values. The first submition gets the 1 values, the rest get 0 and the following error message:

> Warning: Undefined array key 1 in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\panel_gastos\v1.3\ingreso_problemas.php on line 97**

the screen looks like this:
[image: Page interface]

And here is the result of the submission in mySQL: the first element should have had "recurrente=1" and "resuelto=0"

[image: PhpMyAdmin result]

And the code is the following:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport", content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Portal gastos - ingreso de problemas</title>
        <!---Bootstrap-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cuYeSxntonz0PPNlHhBs68uyIAVpIIOZZ5JqeqvYYIcEL727kskC66kF92t6Xl2V" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!---JQuery-->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.min.js" integrity="sha256-pvPw+upLPUjgMXY0G+8O0xUf+/Im1MZjXxxgOcBQBXU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!---añadir filas--->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                var html = '
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="Prob[]" required="">
                        </td>
                        <td><!---<input type="hidden" name="Recurrente[]" value="0"/>--->
                            <input class="primary" type="checkbox" name="Recurrente[]" value="1">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="KPI[]" >
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="date" name="Fecha[]" required="">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="hidden" name="Solucionado" value="0">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="Solucionado[]" value="1">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input class="btn btn-danger" type="button" name="remove" id="remove" value="remove">
                        </td>
                    </tr>';
               
                var max = 15;
                var x = 1;

                $('#add').click(function(){
                    if(x < max){
                        $("#table-field").append(html);
                        x++;
                    }
                });

                $('#table-field').on('click','#remove' ,function(){
                    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
                    x--;
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
   
 <body>

        <div class="container">
            <form class="insert-form" id="insertform" method="post" action="">
                <hr>
                    <h1 class="text-center">input field</h1>
                <hr>
                    <div class="input-field">
                        <table class="table table-bordered" id="table-field">
                            <!---encabezados--->
                            <tr>
                                <th>Prob</th>
                                <th>Rec</th>
                                <th>KPI</th>
                                <th>fecha suceso</th>
                                <th>solucionado</th>
                                <th>add/remove</th>
                            </tr>

                            <!---enviar data--->
                            <?php 
                                $bdd= new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test_usuarios; charset=utf8mb4", "root", "");
                                $bdd->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);

                                if (isset($_POST['save'])){
                                    $createtime = date('Y-d-m');
                                    $usr = $_SESSION["username"];
                                    $ceco = $_SESSION['ceco'];
                                    $problema = $_POST['Prob'];
                                    $recurrente = $_POST['Recurrente'];
                                    $kpi_sol = $_POST['KPI'];
                                    $fecha_sol = $_POST['Fecha'];
                                    $solucionado = $_POST['Solucionado'];

                                    foreach($problema as $key=>$value){
                                        $save= <<<SQL
                                                INSERT INTO incidentes_cecos(fecha_creacion, usr, ceco, problema, recurrente, KPI_sol, fecha_evento, resuelto)
                                                VALUES('$createtime','$usr', '$ceco','$value','$recurrente[$key]','$kpi_sol[$key]','$fecha_sol[$key]','$solucionado[$key]');
                                                SQL;
                                        $query = $bdd->query($save);
                                    };
                                }
                            ?>
                            <!---campos--->
                            <tr>
                                <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="Prob[]" required=""></td>
                                <td><!---<input type="hidden" name="Recurrente[]" value="0"/>---><input class="primary" type="checkbox" name="Recurrente[]" value="1"></td>
                                <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="KPI[]" ></td>
                                <td><input type="date" name="Fecha[]" required=""></td>
                                <td><input type="hidden" name="Solucionado" value="0"><input type="checkbox" name="Solucionado[]" value="1"></td>
                                <td><input class="btn btn-warning" type="button" name="add" id="add" value="add"></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <center>
                            <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="save" id="add" value="save data">
                        </center>
                    </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

So far i've tried some solutions to send 1 if the checkbox is selected and 0 if not. I'm not sure what is happening, most probably this is bad use of arrays from my part.

Comment: Is this a PHP problem, a HTML problem, or a MySQL problem?

Comment: Also, be warned that your `INSERT` query is highly vulnerable to SQL injection. Have a look at prepared statements to avoid getting hacked

Comment: PHP, and sql injection is on the list to be solved

Comment: `sql injection is on the list to be solved`...sure, but why not just do it the right way the first time? It's not difficult! And in fact it can solve other problems...eg. such as when someone puts a `'` in one of the input fields, and that, when unparameterised, crashes your SQL query due to terminating a string too early.

Comment: `name="Solucionado"` in the hidden field would need to be `name="Solucionado[]"` surely, to match it making an array in the checkbox? Otherwise you can only ever get one of those submitted. Is line 97 `$solucionado = $_POST['Solucionado'];` by any chance? (You didn't actually tell us!)

Comment: Also remember, if you have 15 Checkboxes but only 2 are checked, you will only ever see the 2 that are checked, and they will always be delivered as `Recurrente[0]` and `Recurrente[1]` regardless of which ones were actually checked. So you will need a `value="something to id the actual checkbox checked"`

Comment: @ADyson the hidden field solution only works if there is only one checkbox with that name to begin with - if there are more and we use square bracket syntax in the field names, then the resulting data set will be useless for the purpose of properly correlating the data once again.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="hidden" name="Solucionado[]" value="0">
<input type="checkbox" name="Solucionado[]" value="1">
```

Even if the name of the hidden field was fixed so that it matches that of the checkbox - you can not use this solution, when you have multiple checkboxes with the same name.

If you had

```
<input type="hidden" name="Foobar" value="0">
<input type="checkbox" name="Foobar" value="1">
```

then this solution works - because PHP overwrites parameters with the same name, so `$_POST['Foobar']` would contain the `0` the hidden field submits, if the checkbox was not checked, and `1` if it was (because then both `0` and `1` get submitted under the same name, and the later `1` overwrites the earlier `0`.)

But if you have fields with `[]` in the name, PHP will not overwrite, but create an array with all the submitted values. That is the behavior that you *want* for your text fields of course - but it prevents this checkbox workaround from working.

Because, if you had the above hidden input plus checkbox say, three times, but you check only one of the checkboxes - then that still results in *four* values being submitted: The three hidden inputs all submit their `0`, and the one checked checkbox submits its `1`. So once again, you will not be able to *correctly* correlate that to your text field values.

The only viable solution here is that you explicitly specify the index the value should get in the resulting array, upfront. Your first text input would be named `name="Prob[0]"`, and the checkbox `name="Solucionado[0]"`. And with `[1]` on the next set of fields, and so on. The hidden field gets completely removed.

Since you are dynamically appending the form fields using JavaScript, you will need to modify that part to keep a counter, and modify the output in the relevant places accordingly.

Then you can loop over `$_POST['Prob']`, and then for each entry check if one with the same index exists in `$_POST['Solucionado']`.

But since you need to make modifications in how you create the form to begin with, it might make more sense to change the field names to something like `name="data[0][Prob]"` and `name="data[0][Solucionado]"`. Then you get all the data in `$_POST['data']` organized by numeric index first, and then you have `Prob`, `Solucionado`, etc. below that - with the `Solucionado` still only existing if the respective checkbox was checked. But the data is grouped more logical to begin with.